# Measure Theory: How to prove this statement using one of these results?

Tags: measure-theory

RESULT 1: If $I_1, I_2,\ldots, I_n$ are disjoint open intervals and $E$ is a bounded set such that $E \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^n I_k$ then $m^*(E)=\sum_{k=1}^n m^*(E \cap I_k)$. (where $m^*(S)$ is the Lebesgue outer measure of $S$.)

RESULT 2: If $\{I_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is a disjoint collection of open intervals and $E$ is a bounded set such that $E \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k$ then $m^*(E)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty m^*(E \cap I_k)$.

I have to prove this using one of these results (probably result 1):

If $A$ and $B$ are bounded subsets of $\Bbb R$ and there is a $r >0$ such that $|x-y| \geq r$ for all $x \in A$ and $y \in B$, then $m^*(A \cup B) = m^*(A) + m^*(B)$.

Any hint or idea will be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What if $A=\{0, 2\}$ and $B=\{1,3\}$? $r=1/2$ works and there are not such intervals. Maybe a disjoint union of intervals works?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. You should indeed be able to use a finite disjoint union of intervals for each. It will probably help to consider the set $\{ x \colon d(A,x) < r/3 \}$ and similarly for $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $$U_X = \bigcup_{x \in X} B\left(x,\frac r 3\right)$$ for $X=A,B$. These are open subsets of the real line and thus can be decomposed as countable unions of pairwise disjoint open intervals $U_X = \bigsqcup_{j=1}^\infty I^{(X)}_j$. We also have the following facts:

- $A \subset U_A$, $B \subset U_B$;
- $U_A \cap U_B=\emptyset$ by the given separation condition; so in particular:

  - $I^{(A)}_j \cap B = \emptyset$ and $I^{(B)}_j \cap A = \emptyset$
  - $I^{(A)}_k \cap I^{(B)}_j = \emptyset$ for all $j,k$.

Thus the $I_j^{(A)},I_j^{(B)}$ together form a countable pairwise disjoint collection of intervals covering $A\cup B$, and applying Result 2 we have

$$
\begin{align}
m^* (A \cup B) &= \sum_j \left( m^*((A \cup B) \cap I^{(A)}_j) + m^*((A \cup B) \cap I^{(B)}_j) \right)  \\
&= \sum_j  m^*(A \cap I^{(A)}_j) + \sum_j m^*(B \cap I^{(B)}_j).
\end{align}
$$

Since the $I^{(A)}_j, I^{(B)}_j$ are covers of $A,B$ respectively by disjoint open intervals, we can now apply Result 2 to them individually, giving the desired $m^*(A \cup B) = m^*(A) + m^*(B)$.